# Magento 2 : Product price should be change on custom option select in custom module

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options, widget

In my custom module, I display product on model popup. I set custom option in simple product.

When, I select custom option then, product price should also update as like working in product page.

But, currently it's not update product price.

What should I need to do to apply this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How do you display the popup? You can try a layout xml (should contain a portion of xml from catalog_product_view.xml ), a controller and use an Ajax call to the controller then display the ajax response in your popup.

Comment: I think that you aren't load pdp js on this popup.

Comment: How to load it?